# Show API error on formik like yup message error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, formik, yup

I wrote this code to create a login form using `formik` and `yup`. Now, I'm trying to handle the error from the login `API` but I don't find any usefull example or guide. There is a universal method for handling all possibile API error based on the fields defined on the initialValues fields of `Formik` components or the `yup` schema?

This is my custom `InputText` that just handle the `yup` error:

```
export default function InputText({fieldName, noTop, ...props}) {

  const [field, meta] = useField(fieldName);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.input, {marginTop: noTop ? 0 : 20}]}
        value={field.value}
        onChangeText={field.onChange(fieldName)}
        onBlur={field.onBlur(fieldName)}
        {...props}
      />
      {meta.error && meta.touched && (
        <Text style={styles.error}>{meta.error}</Text>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

And this is the code of the `Login` form:

```
<Formik
  validationSchema={loginValidator}
  initialValues={{
    username: '',
    password: '',
  }}
  onSubmit={ async (values) => login(JSON.stringify(values)) }
>
  <LoginBody/>
</Formik>
```

The `LoginBody` is the body of the login form, that is create using `useFormikContext()`. Its contain two `InputText`: `username`, `password`; and a `button` that, `onPress` call `submitForm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`setFieldError`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfielderror-field-string-errormsg-string--void) inside [`onSubmit`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany) function.

As you can see in the [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany)  the second parameter of `onSubmit` is the formikbag and you can get `setFieldError` from it.

```
onSubmit={async (values, { setFieldError }) => {
    // do what you need to do
    // get the field and the error from the api call
    // set the error message for that field
    setFieldError(fieldName, errorMessage)
}}
```

Comment: the error msg disappears when the page is clicked if a validation schema is implempted.